# Problem in running Open.NAT library for port forwarding

Tags: c#, portforwarding

I am trying to use a library ([Open.NAT](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT)) for port forwarding the problem is that i am getting an ip address that is not actually my external ip address and neither my port is getting forwarded

[Here my External ip Address by this Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiwIB.png)

[My Actual Ip Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrDkg.png)

I treid to 'ping' that external ip address on my pc and that works completely fine but when i do the same with any other pc (which is not connected on my network ) it doesn't respond

```
        var discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
        var device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);
        var ip = await device.GetExternalIPAsync();

        await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 1600, 1700, "The mapping name"));

        Console.WriteLine("The external IP Address is: {0} ", ip);
```

why this library is providing me wrong ip address & my port is not getting forwarded ?

Comment: if your machine does not physically own the external IP it will not be able to port forward for it.    If your machine was 12.45.84.22 or something and you had an internal lan of 10.0.0.x then you could portfoward from 12.45.84.22 (port n) to a 10.0.0.x machine

Comment: @BugFinder Yes , but the problem is this library is not providing me the correct external ip .

Comment: On "Ipconfig" of your machine do you see the external IP assigned? if not thats why the external IP probably comes from your router in which case that has to do the port forwarding